# Python nested dictionary acces by specific subkey

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I want to know which key of the following dictionary belongs to a specific subkey:

```
dic = {'key1':{'subkey1':'entry1', 'name':'entry2'},
       'key2':{'subkey3':'entry3', 'name':'entry4'},
       'key3':{'subkey5':'entry5', 'name':'entry6'}}
```

For example: which key belongs to entry4?

```
for i in dic.keys():
    if dic[i]['name'] == 'entry4':
        print(i)
        break
```

Answer is: key2

Is there an easier/better way to do that?

Comment: `[k for k, v in dic.items() if 'entry4' in v.values()]` ?  Basically the same logic but a bit more compact.

Comment: If you are frequently looking up by `name` you may want to invert your dict to be keyed by `name` for O(1) lookups.

Comment: `next(i for i in dic if dic[i]['name'] == 'entry4')`

Comment: @superbrain `dic[i].get('name')` would be more robust. And maybe make use of the default argument of `next` in case there's no match.

Comment: @masterofpuppets Can you confirm that you only want to search the values with 'name' keys?  In which, case some of these answers are wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dic = {'key1':{'subkey1':'entry1', 'name':'entry2'},
       'key2':{'subkey3':'entry3', 'name':'entry4'},
       'key3':{'subkey5':'entry5', 'name':'entry6'}}

print(''.join(x for x, y in dic.items() if 'entry4' in y.values()))
```

output

```
key2
```

Comment: What is the reason for using `''.join` here?

Comment: @Bill just to remove it in list

Comment: an OP wanted the only word `key 2` not the list contains that word

Comment: The danger is if there are duplicates you get `key2key3key4...`.  I think @Samwise has the best answer in the comments.  Return a list and then you are able to detect duplicates and deal with them.

Comment: can change the separator to `' '` or `'\n'`

Answer (score 0):

As @Samwise already suggested in the comments:

```
[key for key, subdic in dic.items() if 'entry4' in subdic.values()]
```

Out:

```
['key2']
```

Note: it returns a list because there are possibly more than one matches.

If you only care about the first match or if you are sure there are no duplicates you can use:

```
matching_keys = [key for key, subdic in dic.items() if 'entry4' in subdic.values()]
matching_keys[0]
```

Output:

```
'key2'
```

Comment: This is actually not correct because the OP only wants to search the values with `'name'` as the key.